# NavMesh Agent Raycast can't hit anything

Tags: unity-game-engine

In document [NavMeshAgent.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.Raycast.html)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Transform target;
   private NavMeshAgent agent;

void Start()
{
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

void Update()
{
    NavMeshHit hit;
    if (!agent.Raycast(target.position, out hit))
    {
        // Target is "visible" from our position.
    }
}
```

}

P/S : I have try collider and NavMeshObstacle on wall but it doesn't work
I setup my scene like :
[image]
[image]
[image]
"agent.Raycast(target.position, out hit)" alway return false. Can anyone tell me why ?? Document wrong ?? or maybe i setup wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

NavMeshAgent.Raycast interacts with what is called a NavMeshObstacle. I believe to fix this you just need to add a NavMeshObstacle component to the wall. Agents also avoid NavMeshObstacles, but they will pass through a Physical Collider like a Box Collider.

Link to the docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshObstacle.html

Comment: I have try use NavMeshObstacle  before but it doesn't work,  I edit my question.

Comment: @ledien Try to enable the 'carve' option. I am reading into the documentation and I believe it is checking for a NavMesh boundary. With this option enabled, the obstacle will actually carve out the NavMesh, instead of just blocking the Agent from moving. The agent then actively paths around it.